# How to Bitwise OR two binary strings( containing 0's and 1's only ) if the strings are too large? (say string length upto 500)

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, implementation, string-comparison

How to Bitwise OR two binary strings( containing 0's and 1's only ) if the strings are too large? (say string lengths upto 500)

**Example:**

**String 1:** **"1111001000111001101101111100110100110011111000111111011010111111011111111010110011001111001100011101011110011111111110101100010100100001111101010110110110111110100111111001011100011111111000000101011111110110101111111101000111100010111111011111110101010110111010101010110111110110011010010011011101111"**

**String 2:**
**"111010111111111111111110110110011111111101011100011100010011101100111100110001010110111111110100101001111101110111111010111100010111110111101111000111100101011111111001100111111010111111111011111111101010101001000010111111000110010100101101111011111010111000111111010011111100011100101111001111011111"**

**Also, how to parse the resulted binary string to integer? (base 10)**

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: I have tried using parseInt() and then using OR ( ^ ) on integers and converting back to binary. It works for small inputs but obviously it won't work for large inputs..

Answer (score 3):

Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (note the `0b` at the start of the binary strings):

```js
var String1 = "0b1111001000111001101101111100110100110011111000111111011010111111011111111010110011001111001100011101011110011111111110101100010100100001111101010110110110111110100111111001011100011111111000000101011111110110101111111101000111100010111111011111110101010110111010101010110111110110011010010011011101111";

var String2 = "0b111010111111111111111110110110011111111101011100011100010011101100111100110001010110111111110100101001111101110111111010111100010111110111101111000111100101011111111001100111111010111111111011111111101010101001000010111111000110010100101101111011111010111000111111010011111100011100101111001111011111";

var bitwise_or = BigInt(String1) | BigInt(String2);

document.querySelector('#bigint').innerText = bitwise_or; // BigInt (Base 10)
document.querySelector('#binstr').innerText = bitwise_or.toString(2); // Binary String
```

```css
p { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<p id="bigint"></p>
<p id="binstr"></p>
```

Comment: Also, how to convert the resulted binary string to integer? (base 10)

Comment: @HannanKhan Just pass `10` as the base instead of `2` to `toString`

Comment: @HannanKhan The variable `xor` is a BigInt with the base 10 representation, `xor.toString(b)` converts it to a string in base `b` (by default `b = 10`, so `xor.toString()` suffices, however, for future arithmetic manipulations, keep the variable `xor` a `BigInt`).

Comment: @MrGeek How I didn't notice that. I wanted the OR operation not the XOR. So does it work similarly for OR as well ? With only replacing caret ( ^ ) with pipe ( | ) ?

Comment: And does the "0b" at the start of the string also remain the same?

Comment: @HannanKhan Yes it does work similarly, and the `'0b'` remains, it tells `BigInt` constructor that the string entered is a binary number, not a base 10 decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the string with an offset for the index.

```js
function or(a, b) {
    let result = '',
        i = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
        offsetA = a.length - i,
        offsetB = b.length - i;
    
    while (i--) result = (a[i + offsetA] | b[i + offsetB]) + result;
    result = a.slice(0, offsetA) + b.slice(0, offsetB) + result;
    return result;
}

console.log(or('11', '1100'));
console.log(or('1100', '11'));
```